# how to automatically select an option in dropdown box using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```html
<select class="shortinput" name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat_some_id">
    <option value="49">Mp3</option>
    <option value="75">AAC</option>
    <option value="15">Lossless</option>
    <option value="72">Transcode</option>
    <option value="73">Soundtrack</option>
    <option value="82">Radio Shows</option>
    <option value="87">Karaoke</option>
    <option value="16" selected="selected">Other Music</option>
</select>
```

I want to select `MP3` from this dropdown box. There is also another Dropdown box with the same Class. I want to change `Other Music` which is selected at default to `MP3`. What is the jquery code I should be using to achieve this?

Comment: what've you tried already? On what action you want to select it (click, automatically on window load)?

Comment: $( function(){
    $('.nobr').trigger('click');

I've used this to call the dropdown box.. Now i want to select MP3 from the list provided above..

Comment: i want to select MP3 of all the dropdown boxes of the same class and name but different ID's on click

Comment: @Demolisher If you wanted to do something different to what your question asks, why don't you ask it in your question? You can edit the question to ask what you're actually aiming to achieve. Currently, the answer given answers your question correctly.

Comment: Do you want to change the value of the select or do you want to change the text of that option?

Comment: i want MP3 to be selected so that i can save it

Answer (score 2):

Use `val()` method in jQuery and set corresponding value of the option

```js
$('#sub_cat_1089837').val('49');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="shortinput" name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat_1089837">
  <option value="49">Mp3</option>
  <option value="75">AAC</option>
  <option value="15">Lossless</option>
  <option value="72">Transcode</option>
  <option value="73">Soundtrack</option>
  <option value="82">Radio Shows</option>
  <option value="87">Karaoke</option>
  <option value="16" selected="selected">Other Music</option>
</select>
```

Or if you have multiple select tag then try

```js
$('.shortinput').eq(0).val('49');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="shortinput" name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat_1089837">
  <option value="49">Mp3</option>
  <option value="75">AAC</option>
  <option value="15">Lossless</option>
  <option value="72">Transcode</option>
  <option value="73">Soundtrack</option>
  <option value="82">Radio Shows</option>
  <option value="87">Karaoke</option>
  <option value="16" selected="selected">Other Music</option>
</select>
<select class="shortinput" name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat_1089837-1">
  <option value="49">Mp3</option>
  <option value="75">AAC</option>
  <option value="15">Lossless</option>
  <option value="72">Transcode</option>
  <option value="73">Soundtrack</option>
  <option value="82">Radio Shows</option>
  <option value="87">Karaoke</option>
  <option value="16" selected="selected">Other Music</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks but how can i select mp3 from many dropdown boxes with the same class and name but different ID's?

Comment: @Demolisher `$('.shortinput').val('49');`

Comment: Not working.. there is another dropdown box with the same class. So i want to select MP3 from the one given above,, how do i select it?

Comment: @Demolisher `$('.shortinput').eq(0).val('49');` use index of select tag in the page inside `eq()` , `0` means it will change the first select tag value... or just use `id` as selector `$('#sub_cat_1089837').val('49');`

Comment: @Demolisher, this answers perfectly your question. The details you are providing in the comments should be instead added to your main question so that everyone knows exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your help Pranav.. I have edited the OP to what i want to achieve.. I tried what you told me but it didnt work.. any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to select proper `select` object with jQuery. As you have two selects with same class on your site - you need to select those by ID and set value to chosen:

```
$("#sub_cat_1089837").val(49);
```

If you don't know ID, but you know class, and position on site (for example, there are two selects and you need to set last one) you can use class selector with additional `:last` parameter:

```
$(".shortinput:last").val(49);
```

`:last` will filter all selects with `.shortinput` class to only last one, and then `.val()` will change selected value. You can read more in [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/).

Let me know if this helped you.